# Can AES encryption be decrypt on another machine

Tags: .net, aes, config, encryption

Can AES encryption be decrypt on another machine? Lets say a computer encrypts a config file..will another computer that has AES decrypt code be able to decipher it correctly? Or is it machine specfic?

Comment: As soon as you know a key - yes

Answer (score 1):

AES is an encryption algorithm and is not specific to any particular computer or computer language. It is widely available in many languages and operating systems.

The only secret in the algorithm is the key.